# Circular arrangement with professions and age based puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Eight people, named A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H; who work as a dancer, singer, lawyer, painter, doctor, teacher, architect, and professor; are 25, 40, 45, 29, 66, 24, 21, and 34 years old; although these labels are not necessarily in the given order; are seated in a circle facing the centre. Based on these clues, determine how the eight people are seated.

1. The doctor sits third to right of D.
2. The sum of ages of the neighbours of the doctor is a perfect square.
3. The age of G is equal to, twice the difference in the ages between the one who is to the immediate right of doctor and D.
4. G sits second to the right of the one who is oldest.
5. G is neither architect nor doctor.
6. Only two persons sit between teacher and architect.
7. The one who is the oldest is either painter or lawyer.
8. The difference between ages of neighbours of G is equal to the age of F who is a dancer.
9. H sits opposite to the one who is a teacher and does not sit adjacent to F.
10. The singer's age is an odd number and sits two places away from B.
11. B is adjacent to neither the lawyer nor E.
12. Painter sits adjacent to the one who's age is 29.
13. A sits neither adjacent to the youngest nor opposite to C.

Source: a mock test for entrance to an MBA exam I'm preparing for

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, mrinal! This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. Please could you edit your post to accredit its original source? (We need it so that the original puzzle creator gets the credit, as part of our plagiarism policy...) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be

> The people sit in the following order (counter-clockwise, so seat numbered $n+1$ is immediately to the right of the seat numbered $n$:
>  1. G, aged 40, professor
>  2. B, aged 24, painter
>  3. A, aged 29, doctor
>  4. H, aged 25, singer
>  5. C, aged 34, architect
>  6. F, aged 21, dancer
>  7. E, aged 66, lawyer
>  8. D, aged 45, teacher

Comment: Quick reminder: If you can tell (with reasonable certainty) that the OP is not posting their own content, it's better to point out the attribution/no-plagiarism requirement than to spend time answering a question likely to be closed/deleted.

Comment: @Rubio The OP has specified the source for the puzzle (although very vaguely), but it's clearly stated that the puzzle it's not their own.

Comment: That’s putting it rather generously :)  attribution is giving credit where due, not merely the avoidance of plagiarism (the taking of credit where it’s not due).

Comment: @Rubio As of now, I've found only one [source](https://ru.scribd.com/document/438775921/Quantifiers-Set-of-the-day) of the puzzle, although I doubt that it can be used as "official" one.